# Android Spinner : How to Get the Selected Item Color?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-xml

The strings.xml for color item be:

```
 <resources>
<string name="app_name">My Application</string>
<string-array name="color_array">
    <item><font fgcolor='#123456'>SomeColor </font></item>
    <item><font fgcolor='red'>RED </font></item>
    <item><font fgcolor='green'>GREEN </font></item>
    <item><font fgcolor='blue'>BLUE </font></item>
    <item><font fgcolor='magenta'>MAGENTA </font></item>
    <item><font fgcolor='cyan'>CYAN </font></item>
    <item><font fgcolor='yellow'>YELLOW </font></item>
    <item><font fgcolor='gray'>GRAY </font></item>
    <item><font fgcolor='black'>BLACK </font></item>
    <item><font fgcolor='white'>white </font></item>
</string-array>
```

I would like to get the item's color (the hex values)  inside the onItemSelected:

```
/*Java code*/
Spinner mColorSpinner;  

//get Spinner of xml
mColorSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.color_spinner_id);
//for registering callback of the spinner
mColorSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
     //Spinner to get the selected color
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View selectedItemView,
                               int position, long id) {

              //TODO how to get the text color of the item ?
    }          
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the code which you set "color_array" to the spinner

Comment: Put this line in your oncreate:- 
 String[]  colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.color_array);


And put below line in your onItemSelected
String mStringColor = colors[position];

Comment: You have the position where the user has clicked in the spinner, you also must have the array which contains the data for the spinner. Use the position as an index for the array.

Comment: You mean by in spinner red item should be in red color and green in green and so on.. right?

Comment: I would like to retrieve the color hex to avoid a switch case to determine the color.... the color list might be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Just add code in OnItemSelected

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(0x00000000);
 }
```

Happy Coding....

Answer (score 0):

It seems I could not retrieve the color in hexcode directly. But If the list is xml default color (red, blue..etc) and the string is color name, I could get the hexcode alternatively:

```
 @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedItemView,
                                   int position, long id) {

            String strColor = String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF & parseColor(mColorSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            Log.e("Info", "color =" + strColor );
        }
```